# Jackrabbit Sql2-Query -> DescendantNodeJoinCondition

Tags: jackrabbit

```
idb:photo 
  idb:uploadName jcr:primaryType="idbt:metaData" idb:value="4.jpg"
  idb:size jcr:primaryType="idbt:metaData" idb:value="276757"
  idb:title jcr:primaryType="idbt:metaData" idb:value="Title: 4.jpg"
idb:photo>
```

first of all i cant see my code example!
-> clicked on {} and filed in my code!

i would like to get the information of a photo-node where for example the title is
`Title: 4.jpg`
i have the following query:

```
Query query = queryManager.createQuery("select * from [idbt:photo] as p inner join [idbt:metaData] as c on isdescendantnode(p, c) where c.[idb:value] = 'Title: 4.jpg'", Query.JCR_SQL2);
```

my resultset is empty. it should be filled with my matched node!

what is wrong?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the nodes are stored. Is it metadata-node/photo-node OR photo-node/metadata-node?

In the Query you have **isdescendantnode(descendent, parent)**, don't you? Is it a child node? have you tried **ischildnode**?. Take a look at http://www.h2database.com/jcr/grammar.html#join

What version of JackRabbit are you using? How do you know that the result is empty? If for some reason you are using query.execute().getRows.getSize() to try to get the total number of results first, look at this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2765

Comment: it is stored like you see it above! the node-type is idbt:metadata. I have got the following queries which work: Query query = queryManager.createQuery("select * from [idbt:photo] as p right outer join [nt:base] as c on p.id=c.parentid where c.[idb:value] like '%4.jpg%'", Query.JCR_SQL2); and Query query = queryManager.createQuery("select * from [idbt:photo] as p right outer join [nt:base] as c on isdescendantnode(p, c) where c.[idb:value] like '%4.jpg%'", Query.JCR_SQL2); How can i make the synatax-highlighting?